# JavaScript googlemaps read coordinates from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, csv

I want to display some markers using googlemaps. The information (coordinates) are stored in a local *.csv file (wich I want to use a "ressource-file").

How can I read this *.csv file? If I use "jQuery.get('myFile.csv', function (data) {..." it dosn't work.
The error message is: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

Do I hava to make a file selection to read the file? Is there no other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you are trying to load data from a file and not a running server(for example by double-clicking the `.html` from your file manager)?

If your are on the `file://` protocol (which you can see in your url) this will not work. You could try changing to the development directory and runnig `python3 -m http.server` which will start a small development server. You can than change to  `http://localhost:8000` and see if it works.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do: running the data from a file by double-clicking the .html  file. And yes, it is the file:// protocol

Comment: which operating system are you on?

Comment: Then I recommend installing python if you do not have it installed already (https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), opening a cmd.exe, changing to the location that your `.html`-files are in and running the command mentioned. It really is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Thank you, gonna try it.